# Plotly with real time visualization

Tags: jmeter, real-time, data-visualization, plotly

I would like to use plotly to visualize my application response times.

I have data getting generated in a log/csv file which has a timestamp associated with it, but is not logged by the ascending or descending order. Since these are response time values, the timestamps are not really in order.

In order to graph such logs/csv's , how does one approach so that visualization is proper. how is this data visualized in real time? How is the ordering done in real time so that the graph is correct.

I am trying to plotly, so if someone can help me in explaing in plotly language, it would be awesome.

Edit..

Here is how the jmeter logs looks like.

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Filename,Latency,SampleCount,ErrorCount,Hostname,Connect
1449603672335,1336,HTTP URL,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,135143,2,2,http://SiteName,,447,1,0,HostName,208
1449603673533,817,HTTP URL,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,135147,2,2,http://SiteName,,316,1,0,HostName,46
1449603674720,622,HTTP URL,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,135149,3,3,http://SiteName,,213,1,0,HostName,51
1449603675364,588,HTTP URL,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,135151,3,3,http://SiteName,,200,1,0,HostName,47
1449603675511,628,HTTP URL,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,135147,3,3,http://SiteName,,235,1,0,HostName,44
```

Comment: The timestamp is a jmeter timestamp? Is the timestamp from when the request is sent out, or when the response is received? Could you post an extract from your log?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for but: Since these are response time measurements, do you really care for perfect order? If you're worried about labels, I suggest you add `timeStamp` and `elapsed` values which will give you the time stamp of sample end - and this will be in proper sorted order in the log.

You can also set `sampleresult.timestamp.start=false` to record the sample end timestamp in the log instead of sample start timestamp.

Comment: If I don't care about the order by which timestamp are ordered then graphs looks bad. Till I order the timestamps the graph doesn't come out correct.

Comment: Maybe there should be a way for jmeter to output the logs in an order. Do you know how?

Comment: `sampleresult.timestamp.start=false` default is true